# Handling HTTP 303 redirects in zf2

Tags: php, http, zend-framework2, request, response

I am building a small CMS system in zend framework 2. My new website will have a new url structure and I would like to create 303 error handler.

The ideal solution:

The user or search engine will visit the website via old url if page was not found it will check the list of old url stored in (db or array) if url found it will create 303 redirect. If the url was not found in the list it should create 404 page.

Example of urls:

the old (none exiting) url: www.example.com/category/product123.html this should be redirected to the new url: www.example.com/category/product-name/

In total i will have over 100 old pages that need to be redirected to the new url.

How should i do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP 303](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303) is a custom redirect header, not an error and should be used after a HTTP POST. If preserving some legacy url's is what you want (for SEO purposes etc..) you may consider using [HTTP 301 - Moved Permanently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) header.

There are several ways exists to redirect any HTTP request to any other resource in both *Http Server* and *application* level. I would prefer nginx/apache level. Example for nginx:

```
server {

  # ...

  location ~ "^/category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).html" {
      # Example: http://www.example.com/category/product123.html
      # The $1 will be product123 
      return 303 http://www.example.com/category/$1;
  }

  # ...

}
```

Now, calling the old `/category/product123.html` url after reloading your http server's configuration will produce a response similar to this :

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Server: nginx/1.X.0
Date: Tue, 07 Oct 2014 20:47:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 168
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.example.com/category/prodct123
```

In application level, you can easily redirect requests inside any controller action returning by a valid [Response](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Http/PhpEnvironment/Response.php) object:

```
public function anyControllerAction()
{
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', 'http://www.example.com/category/prodct123');
    $response->setStatusCode(303);
    return $response;
}
```

Hope it helps.